# Trim characters from end of string?

Tags: c, string, ansi-c

I am trying to trim the end of a ANSI C string but it keeps seg faulting on the `trim` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void trim (char *s)
{
    int i;

    while (isspace (*s)) s++;   // skip left side white spaces
    for (i = strlen (s) - 1; (isspace (s[i])); i--) ;   // skip right side white spaces
    s[i + 1] = '\0';
    printf ("%s\n", s);
}

int main(void) {
    char *str = "Hello World     ";
    printf(trim(str));
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why. I've tried like 15 different `trim` functions they are all seg faulting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `char* str = "Hello world     "`, the string `"Hello World    "` is stored in the read only of the address space. Trying to modify the read only memory causes undefined behavior.

Instead use

`char str[] = "Hello World    ";`

or

```
char *str = malloc(sizeof("Hello World    ")+1);
strcpy(str, "Hello World    ");
```

and then try trim functions...

For more info on how memory is allocated for variables, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/18479996/1323404

Answer (score 2):

The `trim` function is fine, there are two errors in `main`: 1. `str` is a string literal, which should be modified. 2. The call to `printf` is wrong, because `trim` doesn't return anything.

```
int main(void) {
    char str[] = "Hello World     ";
    trim(str);
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to modify a string literal `"Hello World"` being pointed by `str` which leads to the seg fault.

In `main` make `str` an array:

```
char str[] = "Hello World     ";
```

or `malloc` it:

```
char *str = malloc(sizeof("Hello World     ")+1);
```

Although `"Hello World     "` has type `char []` but it is stored in a read only buffer. Check the output [here](http://ideone.com/704MdW). Also this `printf(trim(str));` does not make sense, since you are not returning anything from the `trim` function.