# How are arrays stored on the stack?

Tags: arrays, c, heap-memory, stack-memory

I know how arrays stored on the heap. But how are arrays stored on the stack? Is the complete array pushed to the stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the whole array is pushed on stack.

See the following answer on how variables are allocated on the stack:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18479996/1814023

Comment: so if I create an local array with 100.000 elements, this can cause an stack overflow?

Comment: @NishithJainMR: size of stack and heap are decided by the compiler on Windoze (i.e. at compile-time).  Default on MSVC is 1Mb for each.  Point is though, it is not defined in the C standard.

Comment: (strictly it's the linker rather than the compiler, and only for the main thread, for other threads you can specify the stack size on creation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-options?view=msvc-160 )

Answer (score 4):

Arrays are stored the same no matter where they are. It doesn't matter if they are declared as local variables, global variables, or allocated dynamically off the heap. The only thing that differs is *where* they are stored.