# What is the difference between those two things

Tags: c, string, char

I want to know why I have a compilation error when I try this :

```
char *name = "some_string";
```

And with this I don't have any problem :

```
const char*name = "some_string";
```

or

```
char name[] = "some_string";
```

Comment: Add some tags. For example, what language is this? Helps the right people find your question.

Comment: That shouldn't produce an error, can you provide more context?

Comment: It seems you were doing some string operation like strcat,strncmp etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate [What is the difference between char s\[\] and char \*s in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1704407)

Comment: All three are perfectly legal in C (though the first is potentially unsafe). If you get an error for the first, your probably compiling your code as C++. If you get an error message, you should include it in the question -- and you need to be aware of what language you're using.

Answer (score 2):

When you say

`char *name = "some_string";`

you are declaring a pointer to `"some_string"` and pointers are used to point already existing data and the existing data here is `"some_string"` which is placed under **read only memory**.

So `const` keyword is important.

`const char*name = "some_string";` // this is proper way

and modifying the `"some_string"` after this declaration is illegal and causes `undefined behavior`...

When you say `char name[] = "some_string";`, `"some_string"` will be placed under read only memory and the same is copied to `name[]` array. later you can modify the content of `name[]`.

For more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/18479996/1814023