# some issue with string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

i'm reading the C programming language, question 2-4 asks to write a function called squeeze to delete all char in s1 which is in s2, so i write the code, but it can't run at all.

here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void squeeze(char s1[], char s2[]);

int main()
{
    squeeze("tabcdge", "abc");
}

void squeeze(char s1[], char s2[])
{
    int i, j, k;

    for (i = k = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        for (j = 0; s2[j] != '\0' && s2[j] != s1[i]; j++)
            ;
        if (s2[j] == '\0')
            s1[k++] = s1[i];
    }
    s1[k] = '\0';
    for (i = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; i++)
        printf("%c", s1[i]);
}
```

Comment: What would be your output in this case??

Comment: Can you give this question a meaningful title? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some title ideas.

Comment: [See **here**](http://ideone.com/yRxumu) for how the duplicate link relates to your code..

Answer (score 1):

In `main`, you pass string constants to `squeeze`. But then `squeeze` tries to modify them with code like `s1[k++] = s1[i]`. You can't modify a constant -- that's what makes it a constant.

Answer (score 0):

String literals (like `"tabcdge"`) are *read-only*. Attempting to modify one leads to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 0):

The String constatns are stored in read-only memory. As @Joachim said, modifying them (deleting in your case) is `Undefined behaviour`.

I suspect your program is crashing. For more info where the variables and constants are stored https://stackoverflow.com/a/18479996/3747770